# how to skip enumerate encoding exception in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, codec

I crafted script and preprocessed large csv for importing to database:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-16') as _f:
    for i, line in enumerate(_f):
        try:
            .... some stuff with line ...
        except Exception as e:
            ...
```

But at some point it gives me exception on `enumerate` :

```
...
  File "/Users/elajah/PycharmProjects/untitled1/importer.py", line 94, in main
    for i, line in enumerate(_f):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/utf_16.py", line 69, in _buffer_decode
    return self.decoder(input, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 0: truncated data
...
```

How to skip broken lines in file not interrupting the script flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the parameter `errors="ignore"` to `open`, to tell Python that you don't care about encoding errors when reading from the file.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], errors="ignore") as _f:
```

This *may* behave oddly however, since it will just skip the invalid bytes, not the whole line the invalid bytes showed up on.

If the behavior you need is to ignore the whole line if anything goes wrong with the decoding, you might be better off reading the file in binary mode and trying the decoding yourself inside your `try`/`except` block, inside the loop:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'b') as _f:
    for i, line_bytes in enumerate(_f):
        try:
            line = line_bytes.decode('utf-16')
            # do some stuff with line ...
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
```

A final idea is to fix whatever is wrong with your file's data so you don't get decoding errors when reading it. But who knows how easy that is. If you're getting the file from somewhere else, out of your control, there may not be any practical way to fix it ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You ignore an exception by catching it and the doing nothing

```
    try:
        .... some stuff with line ...
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        pass
```

But it will depend on the situation if that is really what you want.

You can find the name of the exception in the last line of the stack trace

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 0: truncated data

Comment: Thanks i've tried this but in this case the thing is it is occurring during the `enumerate` function calling, and the only possible solution i see is not to use it...

Comment: You could put the entire `for ... in enumarate()` block inside the `try:` block. But it would probably be better to use `try:` in your `importer.py` script, where the initial error happens, and try to fix the error there.